# Django CSRF with Angular frontend served from different domains

Tags: django, angular, django-rest-framework, docker-compose, django-csrf

I have a dockerized Django backend that uses DRF, django cors headers to allow communications over localhost to the Angular app.

The docker-compose.yml file looks like this:

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    volumes:
      - ./postgres/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
  backend:
    container_name: backend-dev-diary
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./build/backend/dockerfile
    command: sh -c "python manage.py migrate && python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
    volumes:
      - ./backend/dev_diary:/code
    ports:
      - "8005:8000"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_NAME=postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
    depends_on:
      - db
  frontend:
    container_name: frontend-dev-diary
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./build/frontend/dockerfile
    command: sh -c "npm install && ng serve --poll 2000 --host 0.0.0.0 --disable-host-check"
    volumes:
      - ./frontend/dev-diary:/code
    ports:
      - "8080:4200"
    depends_on:
      - backend
```

I want to use session based auth and csrf protection on angular. In the django settings I've set:

```
CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
        "http://localhost:8080",
]

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    "DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES": ["rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated"],
    "DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES": [
        "rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication",
    ],
    "DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS": "rest_framework.pagination.LimitOffsetPagination",
}

CSRF_COOKIE_SAMESITE = "Lax"
SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE = "Lax"
CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = True
SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = True
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = [
    "http://localhost:8080",
]

if DEBUG == False:
    CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
    SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
```

Now I created an endpoint that generates a `CSRF` token and I read the value in Angular. Now when I make a request I include credentials and set the `X-CSRFToken` header with the value that I got from the `CSRF` endpoint.

For a prod environment I would have `nginx` expose the angular app.

Is this the best approach? Could I put `SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = False` and just have angular automatically read the `CSRF` value from the cookie and set the `X-CSRFToken` header for requests like in the docs and just change the name of the cookie to correspond with the one django sends (https://angular.io/guide/http-security-xsrf-protection) or is that unsafe, since client site java would be able to read the cookie?

Is there maybe another approach that would be better than both?

Answer (score 1):

Your current technique of handling authentication and CSRF protection—using Django's `SessionAuthentication` and CSRF defence while having Angular read the CSRF value from a cookie and set the `X-CSRFToken` header—is a reliable and secure one. It adheres to accepted industry standards. However, if you choose to let Angular automatically read the CSRF value from a cookie and set the header, be sure to rename the cookie to comply with Django's conventions while implementing strict security measures to prevent client-side JavaScript access to the cookie. The effectiveness of both strategies can be achieved, but security must always come first, especially in environments that are used for production. The authentication and CSRF protection mechanisms for your Django and Angular application can be kept up-to-date, secure, and dependable by following these procedures and setups.

Hope this helps, do let me know if there is anything I can do.